# OIM - How to import provisioned resources from another OIM version?

Tags: oim

i need to import users and their provisioned resources from the version 11.1.1.3 to 11.1.2.2.
For the users I have used the Bulk Load but this script just only import the user data into the usr table and I need to import also the data about the entire info for the provisioned resources such AD, SAP, CRM, etc.
Could you suggest me any idea to do this? Is there a script or similar to import?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple if your targets are remaining same and then just you need to install all your connectors on 11.1.2.2 machine and the point the connector to targets using IT Resource Configuration. With the help of target Reconciliation you can able to import the provisioned resources to users as it is.

Comment: @BombolOne  if solution resolve you query then please close the question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the user account data in OIM.
1.  Configure target reconciliation and reconcile the user accounts.
2.  Bulk load utility also provides an option to  bulk load account data.
Refer below link.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/dev.1112/e27150/bulkload.htm#OMDEV1769